# Decosnstructing object in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

I have this kind of structure:
[image]

I want to acces uri as key and its value as value.
How i should do it?

This is what I tried and the key I get is **images** rest of the data is value

```
const ImagesToDisplay = images => {
  let imagesMap = Object.entries(images);
  console.log('Images object' + JSON.stringify(images));
  return (
    <View>
      {imagesMap.map(([key, value]) => (
        // <Image style={styles.avatar} key={key} source={key + value} />
      <Text>{key}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

I need to deconstruct this data so i could store it as image, because there is base64 image.
I have commented my Image component now, for debugging

This is how i read data from firebase:

```
readUserData() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({
          id: data.fbid,
          profilePictureUrl: data.profile_picture,
          nickname: data.nickname,
          userInterest: data.userInterest,
          description: data.description,
          images: data.images,
        });
        // console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

to **ImagesToDisplay** i pass this.state.images
Console.log(images) looks like this
[image]
uri is base64 so its very long

Comment: What are you using for storage?

Comment: Firebase realtime-database

Comment: Ok. If you're using the [Rnfirebase SDK](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage). You should be able to load the images collection then iterate over it.

Comment: Ok, but I want to deconstruct object, not change database functions.
Because I fetch not only images data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for help I edited the method, so in Object.entries I pass images.images and it solves problem.

```
const ImagesToDisplay = images => {
  let imagesMap = Object.entries(images.images);
  // console.log('Images object' + JSON.stringify(images.images));
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      {imagesMap.map(([key, value]) => {
        return <Image style={styles.avatar} key={key} source={value} />;
        // <Text style={styles.avatar}>{key}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it looks like the key will be "M..." image name, i think in your case it will work if you do

`Object.values(images).map(el => 
{ 
 return <div key={Object.entries(el)[0][0]}>{Object.entries(el)[0][1]}</div>)})`

It will be much clearer if you posted the actual images array that you receive from db

Comment: updated the question, with images object console.logged.
With your answer I get value as: {"-M5vHVgJ9EXTYRgJmdyT":{"uri":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ
So we are near the answer

Comment: If I console.log(Object.entries(el)[0][1])) it gives images.

Comment: yes, and the other one gives you the key, i am not sure what you want then

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.values(images).map(obj => Object.entries(obj)).flat();`

Example:

```js
const images = {
  'jssjsks': { uri: 'uri1' },
  'wjqwhqwj': { uri: 'uri2' }
};

let imagesMap = Object.values(images).map(obj => Object.entries(obj)).flat();

// 1. `Object.values(images)` returns `[{ uri: 'uri1' }, { uri: 'uri2' }]`
// 2. Then `.map(obj => Object.entries(obj))` returns `[[['uri', 'uri1']], [['uri', 'uri2']]]`
// 3. Finally `.flat()` produces the wanted result `[['uri', 'uri1'], ['uri', 'uri2']]`

// console.log(imagesMap)

imagesMap.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(value)
})
```